# How to play YouTube video in PIP mode like WhatsApp?

Tags: android, android-studio, youtube, youtube-api, android-picture-in-picture

I am building an android app, in that app when a user clicks on the youtube link, it should play in PIP mode like WhatsApp. I am using [Youtube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/). I tried [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture), but the whole app goes into PIP mode and I don't want that. Here is the 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbMXl.jpg) of how PIP works in WhatsApp.

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following link to make an activity work in Picture in Picture mode.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture

And then implement YoutubePlayerAPI into the Activity.

Answer (score -1):

They are using YouTube SDK.
YouTubePlayerView - is the way.

You can have the sample app from [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications)

Comment: Personally I do not know why downvites?!?, since the YouTubePlayerView is the answer